# Adding days to date in php

Tags: php, datetime

I read about this but does not working for me. Here is my code:

```
$today = date_create()->format("d/m/Y"); // Today is 25/04/2013
$num_days = GetNumberOfdays();
$end_date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($today . " + $num_days days"));
```

The value that I get from `$end_date` is  `31/12/1969`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly, is it that you want to get?

Comment: It looks like your `strtotime` string needs to be reversed. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like you're trying to do, you don't even need $today (as it defaults to now if date is not supplied), so you could just do eg:

```
 $end_date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("+ 5 days")); 
 echo $end_date;
```

result would be

```
 30/04/2013
```

if you want to provide a date, you need the parameters the other way round, as per [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$end_date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("+ $num_days days", time()));
```

EDIT: I changed the `$today` variable to just `time()` which is essentially getting you the same information if you're just looking for today's date.

Comment: @Overflow012 I updated my answer. Try that out and see if it works for you.

Comment: I checked it with `var_dump()` And I get an int so it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

`date_create()` return a `DateTime` object.

You could use [DateTime::modify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new \DateTime(); // Defaults to Today
$num_days = 123;
$date->add(
    new \DateInterval('P' . $num_days . 'D')
);
echo $date->format('d-M-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = date_create()->format("d/m/Y"); // Today is 25/04/2013

$num_days = date_create()->format("d");

echo $end_date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime(" + $num_days days"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
// note change of $today format
$today = date_create()->format("d-m-Y"); // Today is 25-04-2013
$num_days = GetNumberOfdays();
$end_date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("+" . $num_days . " days", strtotime($today)));
?>
```